# Package load error in anaconda and Spider

Tags: python, numpy, web-crawler, ipython, anaconda

I have three python 2.7 files edit in Spider 3.1.4 in Anaconda 4.3.1

```
(1). TestClass.py ：Just define a class 
import numpy as np
class TestClass:
    def getArray(self):
        return np.zeros((3,4));
(2). a1.py
from TestClass import *;
tt=TestClass();

(3). a2.py
#just a empty python file
```

When I "runfile" "a1.py" in Spider, a TestClass instance tt was created, and I run following code in Spider's IPython console:

```
>>>tt.getArray()
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

It works correctly, but after I runfile a2.py (a empty file) in Spider, and I re-run  "tt.getArray()" in Spider's IPython console, the error occours:

```
tt.getArray()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-50cc0c83ed77>", line 1, in <module>
    tt.getArray()

  File "TestClass.py", line 6, in getArray
    return np.zeros((3,4));

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zeros'
```

the numpy became missing,  in my experience any "runfile" operator in Spider will lead to missing numpy. Any code about "tt" can't not write in a2.py because tt alread imported package are missing when run a new file.
  Is this a bug ?   Or Spder, Ipython need further configure or set parameter?  Or "runfile" command in spider need additional paramter?

I have go mad with this error, please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package load error in anaconda and Spyder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061754/package-load-error-in-anaconda-and-spyder)

Answer (score 0):

The "Spider" is "Spyder" I make spelling mistake.

Spyder is development environment in anaconda

Because Spyder have "User Module Reloade (UMR)" Property, we us "runfile" function run a script, Spyder will reload all the user created modules.

In my environment, Spyder reload TestClass but not reload numpy, and TestClass bounded numpy was unloaded, so "runfile" can cause users modules invalid.

In "Tools->Preferences->Python Interpreter" we can close UMR

Comment: "The "Spider" is "Spyder" I make spelling mistake." - So why you didn't correct it in your question?